# Custom GitHub Action failing with MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: github-actions

I have a basic custom js GitHub action which is executing a fetch call to an API. However, I'm getting a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error. I've tried different versions of node-fetch etc but haven't been able resolve the error. Has anyone encountered this error? And if so do you know how to resolve?

My Action repository is https://github.com/ReleaseNotesHub/GitHubPullAction

**Error**
Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/GitHubPullAction/GitHubPullAction/node_modules/is-plain-object/dist/is-plain-object.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:297:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:784:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object. (/home/runner/work/GitHubPullAction/GitHubPullAction/node_modules/@octokit/endpoint/dist-node/index.js:5:21)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: '/home/runner/work/GitHubPullAction/GitHubPullAction/node_modules/is-plain-object/package.json',
requestPath: 'is-plain-object'
}

Comment: Hey, please narrow down the problem to a single command that doesn't do what you expect it to do and paste that here. Just linking your repository and showing the error message means whatever solution is given to you will likely not be helpful for other people in the future.

Comment: @rethab Speaking as the person from the future facing the same bug, PatrickNolan's description contained everything relevant.  Shame there wasn't a solution in this post when I found it.

Answer (score 4):

The file `node_modules/is-plain-object/dist/is-plain-object.js` (which it's looking for) is not in your git repo.  It's in your local client, but `git add .` is ignoring it because `dist/` is in your `.gitignore`.   This is a very default setup, but it breaks github actions.

Comment: thx for pointing out that git cannot find the neccessary file since we are ignoring it!